# RegisterClientScriptBlock parameters usages in real scenarios?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, scriptmanager, registerclientscriptblock

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVjHt.jpg

[image]

I never understood the real usage of the `Control` , `type`,`key` usages of this class.

In general Ive always used with : `this , GetType() , "xx"`

but now I truly want to understand .

---

msdn :

**Control** : " the control that is registering the client script"

*so...? what difference does it makes who registered it ? the script will be in the head of the page..*.

**Type**:  "the type of the client script block"

*type ??? its javascript. why does he want another type from me ?*

**Key**:  "a unique indentifier"

*That I can understand - for cases which later to remove... but I'd love for some more advanced explanations*

Can I have please ,  a **real** life scenario in which I  **TRULY** have to play  with those params ?

Comment: Nice question indeed. I was also wondering the same answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the most important part is Control
which control in html tags you want to register the script
for example if you have user control and you want to run the script just for that use this line

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertscript", "document.getElementById('userControl_h1TAG')", true);
```

but when you want to register the block and script to all part of that **page** use this line in CS code of user-control  :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertscript", "document.getElementById('page_h1TAG')", true);
```

Comment: Are you really sure about that? The javascript will have access to the whole html page, so you can access every element on the page even though you register it for the control.

Comment: you are right 
but when you use UpdatePanel there will be problem

[link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=200)
-

Answer (score 1):

The method `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` calls behind the scenes to the internal method `System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` that uses the parameter **control** to make a call to `System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` by referencing `control.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

So, actually when you making a call like this:

```
MyScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertScript", "alert('hi')", true);
```

It's identical to calling:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alertScript", "alert('hi')", true);
```

The **type** parameter comes handy when two different types trying to register scripts with identical string keys.

Comment: So what makes the script unique ? the key ? or combination of type plus something ? and why the constructor wants from me the control && type ?? can you give a real life scenario ?

Comment: The method `System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` generates internally a new key based on the values of the parameters type and key.

Comment: what happens  when two different types trying to register scripts with identical string keys?

Comment: In such case ClientScriptManager registering TWO different script blocks with different keys. The key resolution works something like this: "TypeA_key", "TypeB_key".

Comment: I think we both are wrong.... its combination of the control+type and not tpye+key

Comment: You can see for yourself. Here is a cite from the reflection of ClientScriptManager class: `this.RegisterScriptBlock(CreateScriptKey(type, key), script, ClientAPIRegisterType.ClientScriptBlocksWithoutTags);`

Answer (score 0):

After looking on MSDN I found the method with slightly different parameters, but I think the answers should give you more insight: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx) :

**Control**: Client script blocks that are registered by using this method are sent to the page *only when control represents a control that is inside an UpdatePanel control that is being updated*.

**Type**: This parameter is usually specified by using the typeof operator (C#) or the GetType operator (Visual Basic) to retrieve *the type of the control that is registering the script*.

And I guess the key just is for making sure that one codeblock is not included twice? Or it gives you a warning if you use the same key again?